# ServicesDaemonManager interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, swiftui, ios14, swiftui-14.3-defect

I'm getting a memory error when I try and access the keyboard in another view, that has nothing to do with fetching contacts. The view I am in allows one to update information via `TextField` and the other view, `Contact.swift` is where I get the crash.

In any event, I'm getting a black screen before crashing and seeing these errors.

**[ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke**

**Error communicating with XPC Service: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 0 named**

Here's the code:

```
 static func fetch(_ completion: @escaping(Result<[Contact], Error>) -> Void) {
        let containerID = CNContactStore().defaultContainerIdentifier
        let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: containerID())
        
        let keysToFetch = [
            CNContactImageDataKey,
            CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
            CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,
            CNContactGivenNameKey,
            CNContactFamilyNameKey,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
            CNContactEmailAddressesKey
        ] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        
        do {
            let contacts = try CNContactStore().unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
            completion(.success(contacts.map({ .init(contact: $0)})))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

I'm specifically crashing on the line

```
let contacts = try CNContactStore().unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
```

with `unifiedContacts` alone underlined as the issue. I can't even tap on the tab, now. It either crashes Xcode or my app, entirely.

### UPDATE

So the line:

```
let contacts = try CNContactStore().unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
```

is what's crashing, but only when I use this predicate

```
.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: containerID())
```

There are different predicates I can use to limit the fetch, such as `class func predicateForContacts(matchingName name: String) -> NSPredicate` .

I believe the issue is I am fetching all the contacts at once. Yes, I am doing so on a background thread, but it seems my app cannot handle fetching all my contacts at once in the way I am doing so.

### UNRESOLVED

I still haven't solved this issue. I am using instruments and have 6000+ leaks that I believe are coming from fetching contacts. Can anyone describe what this means? I know it's a retain cycle but without anything in the call stack, I have no idea where to begin so I'm basically beginning everywhere.

[image]

Of course there is no stack trace. May have to rearchitect the app.

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Which env did you use?

Comment: @Asperi Xcode 12.3 / iOS 14.3